# Will my Mac run slow if I update it to Mavericks?

Tags: macos

Today my Mac wanted me to upgrade it to Mavericks. I'm hesitating because it is a bit old (Mid 2009 MacBook Pro) and I don't want things to run slow. I'm currently using 10.8.5 and it is OK. I have a Core 2 duo (2.53 GHz) with 4 GB of RAM.

What do you recommend? How was your experience?

Comment: Not sure it helps, but in terms of general work, I haven't noticed a huge improvement in speed on my quad-core early-2012 MBP, but I do think there has been some. I have noticed that animations seem more smooth and responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine's the same as yours (MacBook Pro 2009 2.53 GHz) and I've definitely noticed it's slower than before.

Comment: Are there specific tasks you experience to run slower or is it a more overall feeling?

Comment: i have exact same computer. it is not what you just feeling that slow but physical computation on this new OS seems too heavy lifting even under intel SSD. {iMac 27' 2012, Macbook Air 13', Macbook Pro 2009 2.53 user}

Answer (score 17):

No, it should run faster.

I have installed Mavericks on three machines:

1. A 2007 iMac
2. A 2010 Macbook Air
3. A 2012 Mac Mini

All models are displaying noticeable speed improvements. Mavericks also freed up a substantial amount extra hard drive space on all my devices.

Comment: couldn't agree more, mavericks really is faster. the only thing I've noticed is when switching between spaces i see a very small stutter motion, nearly noticeable, probably fixed with updates tho :)

Comment: Speed improvements as compared to 10.8, I assume? Also compared to older OS's like 10.6?

Comment: Yes. I've observed speed increases along with each OS update on my older machines.

Comment: I have upgraded my macbook yesterday. Everything runs slower than before. I don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2011 Air and it ran more slowly at first but after rebooting and it seems to run faster than Mountain Lion.

Comment: Whenever the fans spin up on my 2012 Air, I know something's going on.  In the first 24 hours after my upgrade, it rebuilt the Time Machine and Spotlight indices as well as performing several other database upgrade/reindex tasks I assume were required by the upgrade.  It didn't really impact me, but I bet that's where your "more slowly at first" came from.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot slower for me on an iMac 2011.